# Highcharts doesnot reload or re-render chart on value change

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-hooks

I have created donut chart in highcharts, in which data value changes on select of a dropdown.

[Codesandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-36dpc?file=/demo.jsx:1448-1458)

On select from dropdown, data changes but chart doesnot re-renders and updated data is also not shown in chart. Chart remains same for any data.

I tried including **oneToOne={true}**. But it also doesnot help.

There are some similar questions regarding same, but they were not helpful for my case.

If anyone got any idea or need any further information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `useEffect` hook and pass `details`in useEffect dependencies, so every time details will change his state useEffect will be trig and your dataValues will be updated:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import PieChart from "highcharts-react-official";

const App = () => {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState("sup");
  let dataValue = [
    ["Firefox", 45.0],
    ["IE", 26.8],
    ["Chrome", 12.8],
    ["Safari", 8.5],
    ["Opera", 6.2],
    ["Others", 0.7]
  ]; //pass default "sup" to datavalue
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
    chart: {
      type: "pie"
    },
    title: {
      text: ""
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        size: "50%",
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: "pointer",
        depth: 35,
        innerSize: 100,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: "pie",
        name: "Browser share",
        data: dataValue
      }
    ]
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(details);
    if (details === "sup") {
      dataValue = [
        ["Firefox", 45.0],
        ["IE", 26.8],
        ["Chrome", 12.8],
        ["Safari", 8.5],
        ["Opera", 6.2],
        ["Others", 0.7]
      ];
    } else if (details === "hola") {
      dataValue = [
        ["Apple", 35],
        ["Guava", 40],
        ["Grapes", 22.5]
      ];
    }
    setChartOptions((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        series: [
          {
            type: "pie",
            name: "Browser share",
            data: dataValue
          }
        ]
      };
    });
  }, [details]);

  async function newfetchVendor(e) {
    if (!!e) {
      setDetails(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={newfetchVendor}>
        <option value="sup">sup</option>
        <option value="hola">hola</option>
      </select>
      <PieChart
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={chartOptions}
        oneToOne={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit Highcharts React Demo (forked)]